# SolveThis system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, warning-messages

```
solns=Solve[{k^6 - ((k Sqrt[π] - E^(w^2/k^2) π w Erfc[w/k]) (2 (k^2 + 8/Sqrt[π]) w^2 + (16 k^2 ((k Sqrt[π] - E^(w^2/k^2) π w Erfc[w/k])/(2 k) + (k Sqrt[π] (k^2 - 2 w^2) + 2 E^(w^2/k^2) π w^3 Erfc[w/k])/(4 k^3)))/Sqrt[π))/(10 k Sqrt[π]) - k^4 ((k Sqrt[π] - E^(w^2/k^2) π w Erfc[w/k])/(k Sqrt[π]) + 1/10 (9 - (3 ((5 (k Sqrt[π] - E^(w^2/k^2) π w Erfc[w/k]))/(2 k) + (k Sqrt[π] (3 k^4 - 2 k^2 w^2 + 4 w^4) - 4 E^(w^2/k^2) π w^5 Erfc[w/k])/(2 k^5)))/(4 Sqrt[π]))) == 0}, w]
```

I need Plot-- w vs k^2--

```
Plot[Evaluate[w /. solns], {k, 0, 3}
```

Any body??

Comment: You will likely need to obtain numerical solutions. Look into `FindRoot`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
   ContourPlot[
 k^6 - (k Sqrt[\[Pi]] - 
      E^(w^2/k^2) \[Pi] w Erfc[
        w/k]) (2 (k^2 + 
          8/Sqrt[\[Pi]]) w^2 + (16 k^2 ((k Sqrt[\[Pi]] - 
               E^(w^2/k^2) \[Pi] w Erfc[
                 w/k])/(2 k) + (k Sqrt[\[Pi]] (k^2 - 2 w^2) + 
               2 E^(w^2/k^2) \[Pi] w^3 Erfc[w/k])/(4 k^3)))/
        Sqrt[\[Pi]])/(10 k Sqrt[\[Pi]]) - 
   k^4 ((k Sqrt[\[Pi]] - 
         E^(w^2/k^2) \[Pi] w Erfc[w/k])/(k Sqrt[\[Pi]]) + 
      1/10 (9 - (3 ((5 (k Sqrt[\[Pi]] - 
                   E^(w^2/k^2) \[Pi] w Erfc[
                    w/k]))/(2 k) + (k Sqrt[\[Pi]] (3 k^4 - 
                    2 k^2 w^2 + 4 w^4) - 
                 4 E^(w^2/k^2) \[Pi] w^5 Erfc[
                   w/k])/(2 k^5)))/(4 Sqrt[\[Pi]]))) == 0, {k, -5, 
  5}, {w, -6, 6}, FrameLabel -> {"k", "w"}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: No, but you helped me with the ContourPlot... Thanks.